# How to use SQL Server Agent Job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-agent

I will need a steps that detect some values and alert me through email.

So I enable Database Email and setup.

I will need a Query that detects and if Value is what I am looking for then, I will need that to be send email alert.

```
SELECT * FROM Worksheet WHERE EffectiveDate > GETDATE() OR Status=5
```

I am only looking for Status 5 and if Effective Date time is less then -5 hours from the current pulling time.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: what exactly you need help with? With setting up the job? With the query? BTW, if you state "for Status 5 and if Effective Date time is less then -5 hours" then you need to replace OR operator with... AND.

Comment: I use OR because, I need Status=5 or EffectiveDate time -5....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Worksheet WHERE EffectiveDate > GETDATE() OR Status=5
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM Worksheet WHERE EffectiveDate > DateAdd(h,-5,GetDate()) AND Status=5
```

As to how to send an email from an Agent job based on the result of a query I have no idea. I'd use SSIS if you have that available. You can run an Execute SQL task to execute your query, store the result in a variable, then execute a Send Mail task based on the presence or absence of data in your variable....

Comment: EXEC HQ_Server_Test.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    profile_name = 'Database_Mail',
    recipients = 'dryu@bevello.com',
    subject = 'Workshee Status',
    query = N'SELECT ID, Style, EffectiveDate, Status, Notes, Title, FromDate, DBTimeStamp
            FROM  Worksheet
            WHERE Status=5',
    attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    query_attachment_filename = 'Worksheet Status.txt'

This how I made query in Steps but not working....anything wrong?

Comment: Hi Richard, I use sendEmail program to send but if there's no data, how can I stop sending email?

Comment: An IF-BEGIN-END block that checks the output of the query and sends the email if there's output? TSQL is pretty limited in terms of conditional logic and processing...